# How to depth search of an ast tree

Tags: python, tree, abstract-syntax-tree

Good morning,

I am trying to use the ast library in python to get each variable of my code.
The problem is that when I try to use the ast.walk it makes a width course of the tree (sorry I don't know if it's called like this) which means that if I ave this code :

```
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        pass
```

The code will return me :

```
{'i': [0, 1], 'j': [0, 1]}
```

Clearly instead of :

```
{'i': [0, 1], 'j': [0, 1, 0, 1]}
```

Which is the result that I am expecting.

And that's because ast.walk will "execute the walk" like this:
First for loop (the i one)
and when it's finished
Sencod for loop (the j one)
and when it's finished : send results.

I saw some where that I can use the ast.NodeVisitor but I didn't found anywhere a tutorial showing how to use it.

I would like to know if you have any idea of where I can find a tutorial (maybe in french) or if you can explain to me this thing or even if there is an other way to do that.

Thak you very much,

Hope you'll have a nice day.

Comment: You should use `NodeVisitor`. But neither `walk` nor `NodeVisitor` evaluate the program, which seems to be what you expect. Please make your needs more clear.

Comment: You might find [Green Tree Snakes](https://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.io/) useful. But it's in English.